# tf.reduce_sum() unexpected result with uint8

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, tensor

Why does `tf.reduce_sum()` not work for `uint8`?

Consider this example:

```
>>> tf.reduce_sum(tf.ones((4, 10, 10), dtype=tf.uint8))
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=uint8, numpy=144>

>>> tf.reduce_sum(tf.ones((4, 10, 10), dtype=tf.uint16))
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=uint16, numpy=400>
```

Does someone know why that is?

The [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_sum) have not mentioned any incompatibility with `uint8`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uint8` stands for unsigned integer, which gets 8 bits in order to keep values.

By 8 bits, you can only save positive numbers (unsigned) in range [0, 255] (If it is `int8` it can keep signed numbers in range [-127,+127]).

If you want to keep a value higher than 255, it only keeps the first 8 bits of that number, e.g. 256 in binary is `0000 0000 1`, and the first 8 bits are `0000 0000`. So, for 256 you will get `0` as the result:

```
>>> tf.reduce_sum(tf.ones((1, 255), dtype=tf.uint8))
    <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=uint8, numpy=255>

>>> tf.reduce_sum(tf.ones((1, 256), dtype=tf.uint8))
    <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=uint8, numpy=0>
```

In your case, the expected result is 400, but since `uint8` cannot keep values higher than 255, it will get start at 0 when the sum gets to 256. So, you see result as 144 which is actually `400-256=144`.

So, it's not on`tf.reduce_sum()`, it's on `uint8`, and take care of using any dtype.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown! I am using very big tensors (e.g. `(4, 400, 976, 976`), so choosing `uint8` was a concious choice to save memory. I was very confident that this should work, as numpy takes care of the value range overflow by automatically upcasting to bigger ints. I went back to the docs and this behaviour was indeed mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_sum#expandable-2).